# How to find MAC or IP address of a device connected to the same Ethernet bridge?

Tags: ip, bridge, mac-address

I have the following topology:

```
DeviceX ------
              |
 DeviceX bridge with two Ethernet cards 
      (created with bridge-utils) ---------------- router 
              |                                      |
              |                                      |
DeviceY ------                                       |
                                                     |
                                     other devices on the same network 
                                       (switches, PCs, WiFi devices)
```

I have complete control over DeviceX - it's a Linux PC and it has two Ethernet adapters, which are bridged with Linux `bridge-utils` to provide LAN access for both DeviceX and DeviceY.

DeviceY is also a Linux PC, but I have no control over it. I know only that it is using DHCP IP address received from the router through my bridge on DeviceX. DeviceY might get replaced with another physical device at any time, thus I can't just look at its MAC address once and keep it - I need to determine MAC address each time my DeviceX boots or when it detects that one of its two Ethernet connections has been reset (cable disconnected and connected again etc.).

It is always guaranteed that only these two devices will be connected to the bridge on DeviceX, and no one else.

There might be many other devices connected to the router, but I need only the address of DeviceY which is always directly connected to one of two Ethernet ports.

It might not be deal-breaker if I also get address of the router itself - it will be known beforehand and I can filter it out, as long as I have adresses of only two devices - the router and DeviceY.

Now the question:
**from DeviceX, how do I reliably find MAC or IP address of DeviceY?**

More info:
I use bridge-utils on DeviceX because DeviceY should be in the same LAN as all the other devices in the LAN. Custom routing from DeviceX to DeviceY is not an option because it would create a new subnetwork and it would require NAT and what not to make DeviceY work as expected. Bridge-utils is the simplest solution.

Comment: `brctl showmacs`?

Comment: Or with recent versions of `iproute2`: `bridge fdb show brport eth1`

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas: Thanks, `brctl showmacs br0` did the trick. Is it reliable? Will it show learned MAC adresses even if DeviceY hasn't yet received any data, except some communication with the router to retrieve DHCP lease? If it is reliable, you can add your suggestion as an answer, so I can accept it. It would also be great to have some way to find out also IP for each of the MACs I find with `showmacs`, but that would be another question.

Answer (score 3):

A bridge or switch is a device that bridges two segments of a broadcast domain, and segregates the unicast traffic.

To do that the bridge maintains a forwarding table that records which port reaches a given Mac address. That table is filled in when ever a new packet with a new ethernet source address is received, and MAC addresses that have not been seen in a while are removed.

When a bridge/switch receives a frame intended for a given MAC address, if that MAC address is in its forwarding table, it sends it on the corresponding port only, otherwise to all ports.

The Linux implementation is no different.

The forwarding table can be queried with the

```
 brctl showmacs <bridge-name>
```

And is otherwise available in `/sys/class/net/<bridge-name>/brforward` (binary).

You can get a mapping between port number and interface name with:

```
 grep . /sys/class/net/vmbr0/brif/*/port_no
```

Or, if on a system with a recent version of `iproute2` the new suite of network utilities for Linux, you can get the forwarding table with interface names with:

```
 bridge fdb show br <bridge-name>
```

Or to know all the MAC addresses reachable via a given interface or the bridge, for instance `eth0`:

```
 bridge fdb show br <bridge-name> brport <interface-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `arp` will show all iPs and their MACs, since you only have two computers in your network and the router it will be easy to identify the one that is not your IP nor the router's, and has an IP from your network.

Comment: But there might be lots of other devices in the same LAN connected to the router and having IP adresses in the same range as DeviceX, DeviceY and the router. I can guarantee that only the bridge will have two connections, but not that there will be no other devices in the same LAN. How do I know which of devices returned by `arp` are connected directly to my DeviceX?

Comment: Why does it have to be a bridge? Why not routing from DeviceX instead of bridging?

Comment: Both DeviceX and DeviceY will always be close to each other, but far from a router, therefore I need to connect them both to LAN with only one Ethernet cable. Bridging is the cheapest option. But the main problem is that DeviceX needs to identify, which device it is paired with, and the only thing which makes them paired is an Ethernet cable, that's why I need to find the DeviceY at the other end of the cable.

Comment: Cheapest? routing through DeviceX is for free, unless you don't own that machine and you are being charged for services, otherwise you can route using `iptables`, that way you can have always identified DeviceY

Comment: Routing will create a new subnetwork for DeviceY. I need DeviceY to know nothing about DeviceX (sorry, I did not mention this in the question, I'll update it now). DeviceY should think that it is connected to the same outer LAN as all the other devices connected to the router in my diagram. I could achieve the same with a switch, but switch is more expensive than an Ethernet adapter.

Comment: And installing a DHCP daemon in DeviceX giving IPs only to devices in Ethernet adapter connected to DeviceY and doing NAT won't resolve your problem? Why does it have to be in the same network if it can access that network?

Comment: I'm afraid choosing NAT because both DeviceX and DeviceY might offer various services on various ports. DeviceY has UPnP services and has to be discoverable over the network, and DeviceX also will have UPnP services and, in the future, some other possible services. Thus with NAT it might get too tricky to configure port forwarding correctly. At the end, the pair "DeviceX+DeviceY" will have to be a closed box which "just works" for the end-user, thus everything should be configured as simply as possible.

Comment: Maybe you can have the bridge disabled, and only enable it when Ethernet traffic is detected on the DeviceY side. That way you can identify the MAC address (DeviceY will try to get its DHCP address) so `arp` will give you the MAC, once you have it identified bring the bridge up until the connection is lost, then you bring the bridge down and start all over again.

Comment: One more issue with `arp` is that it shows only learned data for machines with which at least some communication has occured. I just tried - even if I have DeviceY attached to one of the two ports, `arp` does not report anything about it until I send some data (e.g. ping) to it. And I can't communicate with DeviceY before I have found out its IP because I don't know where to send data. Chicken-egg problem.

Comment: Then you can use `tcpdump` on the ethernet device where DeviceY is connected to identify it when it starts sending packets.